# Textarea linhas Editáveis - Thymeleaf e Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, formulário, tabela-banco-de-dados, textarea

Estou construindo um modelo básico de documento, aproveitando a mesma ideia do colega ([Paulo Henrique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2965/paulo-henrique)), só que faço a inserção dos dados por campos externos ao formulário, em um momento anterior de pesquisa do cliente. A dificuldade vem da necessidade de editar este template do texto base do documento, pois algumas vezes é preciso relatar uma situação especial de do cliente. Quando altero o documento, insiro algum dado novo, não estou conseguindo salvar este "novo" documento no banco. Alguém já teve um projeto similar? Já tentei várias alternativas...colocar os novos dados tudo bem, o problema é salvar no banco a alteração.

Estou iniciado com spring + thymeleaf. E o problema base é o seguinte: tenho uma pagina que deve funcionar como um master detail, tenho um objeto "documento", quando clicar nesse objeto preciso que seja carregado na mesma pagina outro objeto (List) referenciado a ele ("campos_documento")

Deixa eu tentar refinar um pouco mais a pergunta: estou usando Spirng+Thymeleaf neste projeto, porém surgiu a necessidade de usar algumas funcionalidade do angular. O problema central é que, depois que adicionei o angular, estou tendo problemas em recuperar as informações do objeto. Os dados simplesmente não aparecem nos inputs. Usei o inspetor de código do firefox para uma análise, e os dados estão carregando no html (value do input), porém não aparecem para o usuário. Meu código esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, não consigo ter uma ideia clara do que está enfrentando, porém, envie os dados do form e imprima a query gerada para gravar no banco para entender o que está ocorrendo, outro ponto é verificar se o nome do campo do form está igual ao que está sendo recuperado.

Comment: Não consegui entender o problema ? Você quer acrescentar um campo no formulário ? Qual campo ?

Comment: @RicardoMota, editei o problema, espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: @wilsonrosagomes, editei o problema, espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Entendi, porém seu problema está na utilização do AngularJS, as informações recuperadas não são colocadas no value do campo que você conseguiria recuperar é inserida em um html gerado pelo próprio código. Analise se a(s) classe(s) CSS que estão no objeto html gerado se não mudam, caso não você deverá recuperar pelo nome das classes as alterações, não esqueça de verificar se está trazendo o ID para efetuar o Update.

Comment: @WilsonRosaGomes. Revisei as classes, mas preciso que, ao digitar algum valor nos inputs, esses valor seja repassados também para um textarea, ex: value do input=xxxxx 
value do text area= Ola {{nome}}
resultado=Ola xxxxx

Isso ja esta funcionando, porem quando seleciono o objeto, os values do input simplesmente não aparecem.